# Searching windows directories for 0KB files

Tags: file, search, cmd, windows-explorer

I have a directory, lets call it 'accounts'. There are ~600 account folders, and in each of those folders, contains an 'IN' folder (among many others).

ex)

```
\\networkfolder\ACCOUNT\account1\in
\\networkfolder\ACCOUNT\account2\in
\\networkfolder\ACCOUNT\account3\in
\\networkfolder\ACCOUNT\account4\in
\\networkfolder\ACCOUNT\account5\in
```

Is there an efficient way/command/tool to scan and output a list of filenames(with their filepaths) in a .txt file that are 0KB in size?

1. Tried advanced search in Windows Explorer, takes too long.
2. Looked into batch scripts, not sure if that will be any better.

I'm trying reduce time by only searching the 'IN' folders in each of the account folders, since those 0KB files are the only ones i'm concerned about.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if that can be done with pure `dir`, but I have a solution with `for`:

```
@echo off
for /r %%S in (in\*.*) do if %%~zS==0 echo %%S is 0 bytes
```

With that, you are looping for every file in directories and subdirectories, and getting his size with `%%~zvar` (In this case `%%~zS`).
Then, use an `if` to see if the size is equal to 0 bytes. If it is, echo to the screen `[full path of file] is 0 bytes`.

Comment: can make that a bit faster with `>file.txt (for /r %S in (in\*) do ...)` (from the question: `only searching the 'IN' folders`)

Comment: Note that the tags for this question suggest the command line [[tag:cmd]] not a [[tag:batch-file]].

Answer (score 0):

This can probably be done with a one-liner `FOR` loop, but this might be more understandable and maintainable in the future. Requires PowerShell 5.1+. If you are on a supported Windows machine, it will have, or can have, Windows PowerShell 5.1.

=== Get-ZeroInFileList.ps1

```
$BaseDir = 'C:\src\t'
$ResultFile = 'C:\src\t\zresult.txt'
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Directory -Path $BaseDir -Filter 'in' |
    ForEach-Object {
        Get-ChildItem -File -Path $_.FullName |
            ForEach-Object {
                if ($_.Length -eq 0) { $_.FullName | Out-File -FilePath $ResultFile -Encoding ascii }
            }
    }
```

Invoke it as a cmd.exe command using:

```
powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -File "Get-ZeroInFileList.ps1"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the quickest way I can think of, if you really need left aligned text file output, and to ignore all 0 byte files not directly inside a directory named `in`

```cmd
(For /F Tokens^=* %G In ('%__APPDIR__%Robocopy.exe "\\networkfolder\ACCOUNT" NULL /L /Max:1 /S /NC /NDL /NJH /NJS /NS^|%__APPDIR__%findstr.exe /EIR "\\in\\[^\\]*"')Do @Echo %G)>"emptyfiles.txt"
```

If the alignment and parent directory don't matter you could output all 0 byte files anywhere within the `ACCOUNT` directory like this:

```cmd
%__APPDIR__%Robocopy.exe "\\networkfolder\ACCOUNT" NULL /L /Max:1 /S /NC /NDL /NJH /NJS /NS>"emptyfiles.txt"
```